# MySQL 8 why is initial response to query slow, speeds up thereafter

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

After several minutes of inactivity (no use of the website) MySQL 8 slow right down. An initial query after non-activity can take a minute but thereafter seconds. The same query (like logging in) would take a second or two if there was activity already on the server.

Has anyone encountered this or know how to correct this behavior? The machine itself has a significant amount of resources, its just the first "warm up" call that is slow.

Comment: How do you know that one query takes longer than the other? If you indicate it, someone may be able to help with that.

Comment: Hard drive spun down? DNS resolution stall?

Comment: more details about your (hardware/software-config) environment are needed to answer this question, without guessing.

Comment: The typical reason for the "first request is slow, subsequent requests are fast" pattern is: caching.